# order by not giving correct output as ascii value of minus (-) greater than plus (+)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

why my table not giving correct output based on ASCII  values. I have written query like     `select * from patient1 order by BLOOD_GROUP DESC;` so, as per my knowledge O-ve,O+ve,...will come as output but my output coming as O+ve,O-ve,...
[image]

Comment: Are you _sure_ that it's an ASCII "minus" sign (ASCII 45) and not some sort of UTF-8 encoded character that looks a bit like one?

Comment: yes its minus(-)

Comment: What is the collation of your table? It can possibly affect the expected sort order.

Answer (score 2):

The ordering works correctly. The ASCII code for `+` is 43, and the ASCII code for `-` is 45, so `+` should indeed come before `-` in lexicographical ordering.

As an alternative solution, you could sort on a boolean true/false of whether the `blood_group` contains the `-` character, and then on the `blood_group` itself so you get your `A`s before your `B`s:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     patient1
ORDER BY blood_group LIKE '%-%' DESC, blood_group
```

Comment: but when i executed in my visual studio, the code which i written above it giving the correct output like O-ve,O+ve,..dont know why the ordering problem is in mysql. anyways thank you...

Comment: *The ordering works correctly* the OP sorts `DESC` and gets `O+ve` before `O-ve`. How is this correct?

Comment: @SalmanA I guess it's a case of a (default?) encoding. I've reproduced this behavior on MuSQL 5.6-5.7.

Answer (score 1):

If the +/- is always in the second position, you can replace them with characters that are ordered as you want:

```
select p.*
from patient p
order by replace(replace(blood_group, '+', '1'), '-', '2')
```

This does not affect the result set, only the ordering.

Comment: thank you. is there any other way to do instead. was trying to figure out why -ve not coming first, as - having higher ascii value than +.

Comment: @user2713675 . . . There are other options.  I think this is pretty simple.